# calling getOwners() within an app script container

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I'm working on a pretty simple tool to ping a site owner when a visitor engages in interesting behavior on the site (specifically, posts a guestbook comment, so the code is in the guestbook app).

Anyway, the code of interest looks like:

```
var siteOwners = SitesApp.getActivePage().getOwners();
for (var i = 0; i < siteOwners.length; i++) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(siteOwners[i].getEmail(), "Comment added to your site", "ping");
}
```

The problem, of course, is that SitesApp.getActivePage() and SitesApp.getActiveSite() both return null in this context.

It's probably the case that this is all happening because rather than use the newer pseudo-GUI app containers, I am doing it all from within a doPost(e) method with HTMLService as the user interface, as both UiService and GUIBuilder were far too slow to be of use (~10 seconds between rendering the base page and rendering the guestbook interface).

Any advice or ideas would be helpful, especially if it involves a "go here and read this whitepaper to understand application environments for appscript".

Answer (score 0):

The `getOwners()` method for a `page[]` class does not exist.
check  out the [page class documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_page#getAuthors)

The `getAuthors()` method does exist maybe you can use that as a solution.

```
function doGet(e) {
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("site owner");
var siteOwners = SitesApp.getActivePage().getAuthors();
 app.add( app.createLabel(siteOwners.length))
 for (var i = 0; i < siteOwners.length; i++) {
   app.add(app.createLabel( siteOwners[i]));
 }
return app.close();
}
```

This did the job for me without the mail thing.

[working example](https://sites.google.com/a/lagaroo.com.br/dev-test/home/dev-test-siteowner)